# Why is whitespace(' ') returning <EOF> in my code?

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr

```
grammar VB6;
/*
* Parser Rules
*/
compileUnit: module+ EOF;
module:declareStmt ;
declareStmt :WS? eqnStmt     #eqStatement; 
eqnStmt: VAR WS? EQ WS? NUM;

/*
* Lexer Rules
*/
NUM:[0-9]+;
VAR: LETTER LETTERORDIGIT*;
EQ : '=';
WS : [ \t]+;

// letters
fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z];
fragment LETTERORDIGIT : [a-zA-Z0-9];

// case insensitive chars
fragment A:('a'|'A');
fragment B:('b'|'B');
fragment C:('c'|'C');
fragment D:('d'|'D');
fragment E:('e'|'E');
fragment F:('f'|'F');
fragment G:('g'|'G');
fragment H:('h'|'H');
fragment I:('i'|'I');
fragment J:('j'|'J');
fragment K:('k'|'K');
fragment L:('l'|'L');
fragment M:('m'|'M');
fragment N:('n'|'N');
fragment O:('o'|'O');
fragment P:('p'|'P');
fragment Q:('q'|'Q');
fragment R:('r'|'R');
fragment S:('s'|'S');
fragment T:('t'|'T');
fragment U:('u'|'U');
fragment V:('v'|'V');
fragment W:('w'|'W');
fragment X:('x'|'X');
fragment Y:('y'|'Y');
fragment Z:('z'|'Z');
```

- Above code is the grammar for variable declaration
- Example 1:     a=12    //Giving no error
- Example 2:    a = 12   //line 1:6 no viable alternative at input (EOF)
- So Here, my question is
  -Why is white space(' ') returning "no viable alternative at input (EOF) " ?
  -Check out my grammar for input : 'a = 12'
  -Note: There is a space between 'a', '=' and '12'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, the grammar cannot read whitespace other than \t. Try add another whitespace characters to the WS rule.